# HSQLDB Embedded in Jar throwing

Tags: scala, sbt, hsqldb

I have an HSQLDB embedded within a fat-jar in the resources directory of the jar. When my script attempts to access the DB, it's throwing an error regarding the lack of a `.lck` file. However, I was under the impression that DB's within jar files would always be accessed in read-only mode.

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@18f6cf91[file =/mnt/c/ctakes/SparkCtakes/jar:file:/mnt/c/ctakes/SparkCtakes/lib/ctakes-assembly-4.0.1.jar!/resources/org/apache/ctakes/dictionary/lookup/fast/sno_rx_16ab/sno_rx_16ab.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/c/ctakes/SparkCtakes/jar:file:/mnt/c/ctakes/SparkCtakes/lib/ctakes-assembly-4.0.1.jar!/resources/org/apache/ctakes/dictionary/lookup/fast/sno_rx_16ab/sno_rx_16ab.lck (No such file or directory)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
        ... 112 more
```

The way I am creating this fat-jar containing the database resources is by placing the resources folder in `src/main/scala/resources` and then using `sbt-assembly` to package everything.

Comment: Add `readonly= true` to the connection URL.

Comment: Modified the string to `jdbc:hsqldb:file:resources/org/apache/ctakes/dictionary/lookup/fast/sno_rx_16ab/sno_rx_16ab;hsqldb.lock_file=false;readonly=true`, but I'm still encountering the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When a read-only database is in a Jar file, the URL to access the database must be a `res:` type URL.

Supposing the top-level directory in the Jar is `org`, the URL would look like this:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:res:/org/apache/ctakes/dictionary/look‌​up/fast/sno_rx_16ab/‌​sno_rx_16ab
```

Comment: Going from your answer earlier, I was able to get it working by going into the database's `.properties` file and entering `readonly=true` there.